# Securely Erase Files on SE/30

Tags: mac, classic-mac-os

I still have an old (venerable) Mac SE/30. I would like to securely erase all my personal files from this machine. How can I SECURELY do that?  Thanks.

Comment: If you can boot it, does the OS in that machine have the equivalent of Disk Utility and with a Secure Erase option?

Comment: I'm amazed the disk still works at all. A Secure Erase would probably kill it. May be get a replacement SCSI drive, and if you can swap it in and install the OS on the new one, then take a hammer to the old one.

Comment: I seem to recall from my old MacWarehouse days that holding down the `Option` key while selecting Empty Trash will securely empty the trash. *However* it's been YEARS since I have had to do anything like that on System 6/7/8/9 (you don't specify) but it may be worth a try. And if you do open the SE/30 **BE CAREFUL** voltage on the CRT is enough to literally kill you, so keep your hands clear of that.